# MongoDB - multiple queries based on condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query that looks something like this.

```
employees.aggregate(
[{ "$match":
 {"$and": [
   {"$or": [
     {name : { "$regex": param, "$options":"i"}},
     {title : { "$regex": param, "$options":"i"}},
   ]},
   { tenure : true }
]}
},
  {"$sort":{experience : -1}},
  {"$limit" : 100}
])
```

I would like to update this query to something like this.

1. search the employees collection where name = param and tenure = true
2. if data exists the  sort the results by experience and limit the results to 100
3. if no results found then search the same collection using title and no need to sort the results.

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a conditional sorting in query. And another important thing is the value of $regex must have in string(" "). You can't pass like

```
$regex: User
```

you need to pass it in string.

```
db.hotspot.aggregate(
[{
        "$match": {
            "$and": [{
                    "$or": [{
                            name: {
                                "$regex": "SD",
                                "$options": "i"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            radius: {
                                "$regex": "250",
                                "$options": "i"
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    infinite: false
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            sort: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $eq: ["$radius", 250]
                    },
                    then: "$name",
                    else: "$_id"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            sort: 1
        }
    }
])
```